# Why are snaps and regular apt packages both provided in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: snap

When I wanted to install Skype on my system, I ended up with my first snap.  Interestingly, it mounted itself as a loopback device and broke my script to mount a crypto filesystem as /dev/loop1.  But Skype was only available as a snap, and I needed it, so...

Since then, I've installed a few open source packages that I would not have expected to be snaps, but were.  Specifically GIMP and the Clementine music player.  Again, I didn't notice they were snaps until I had to move my crypto filesystem to another higher /dev/loop... device.  I had moved it from loop1 to loop9, and thought that would hold me, but having installed the 'visual studio core' text editor to play with I ended up with 6 additional loopback filesystems, in addition to Skype's 3 and GIMP's, and Clementine's.

Personally, I find that really messy.  If a project is truly open source and can be built from source by the distro maintainers, why release it as a snap?  To me, snaps are a necessary compromise for 3rd party closed source developers to get their apps onto multiple distros.  So, Skype I get.  GIMP, no.

It turns out that having uninstalled GIMP and Clementine, I see that Ubuntu (actually Kubuntu - if that makes a difference) has non-snap versions included as well.  Why would they do that - and why would anybody choose the snap over the 'build for the distro'?

Comment: Of course, it is common knowledge that you do NOT have to install Skype as an app.  There are answers available as to how that is done, and done correctly.  Check askubuntu.

Comment: I meant you do not have to install Skype as a SNAP.  Sorry I miss-typed.